# SQL Query-Find percentage improvement, or percentage decline between two tables values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have two temp tables which give me specific job run times for a application.  I'd like to report on the average job timings from month to month.  And then note the differences.

The first query which builds a temp table will output average job timings for the first month, and the second temp table contains average job timings second month.

I'd like to compare the percentage difference for each job, measuring the difference between the second month vs the first month.

Here is an example query building the two temp tables:

--temp table for February's job timings

```
CREATE TABLE #JobTimings_FEB(jobtime int, PRCSINSTANCE int ,
PRCSNAME char (30), PRCSTYPE char (30), RUNSTATUS char (30), 
OPRID char (30), RUNCNTLID char (30), BEGINDTTM char (30) , 
ENDDTTM char (30))--, #Executions char (10))
;
INSERT INTO #JobTimings_NEWSERV (jobtime, PRCSINSTANCE, 
PRCSNAME , PRCSTYPE, RUNSTATUS, OPRID, RUNCNTLID, BEGINDTTM, ENDDTTM)

SELECT DATEDIFF(ss,BEGINDTTM,ENDDTTM) AS jobtime, 
PRCSINSTANCE, PRCSNAME, PRCSTYPE, RUNSTATUS, OPRID, 
RUNCNTLID, BEGINDTTM, ENDDTTM
FROM PSPRCSRQST WHERE BEGINDTTM BETWEEN '2012-02-01 00:00:00.000' 
AND '2012-02-28 23:59:09.837' 
ORDER BY BEGINDTTM
```

--temp table for January's job timings

```
CREATE TABLE #JobTimings_JAN(jobtime int, PRCSINSTANCE int , 
PRCSNAME char (30), PRCSTYPE char (30), RUNSTATUS char (30), 
OPRID char (30), RUNCNTLID char (30), BEGINDTTM char (30) , 
ENDDTTM char (30))--, #Executions char (10))
;
INSERT INTO #JobTimings_OLDSERV (jobtime, PRCSINSTANCE, 
PRCSNAME , PRCSTYPE, RUNSTATUS, OPRID, RUNCNTLID, BEGINDTTM, ENDDTTM)

SELECT DATEDIFF(ss,BEGINDTTM,ENDDTTM) AS jobtime, 
PRCSINSTANCE, PRCSNAME, PRCSTYPE, RUNSTATUS, OPRID, 
RUNCNTLID, BEGINDTTM, ENDDTTM
FROM PSPRCSRQST WHERE BEGINDTTM BETWEEN '2011-12-04 00:00:00.000' 
AND '2011-12-17 23:59:09.837' 
ORDER BY BEGINDTTM
```

As stated above, I would like to find the percentage difference in a query for each job between the two months.

Comment: have you looked at LEAD and LAG functions?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  It may influence the answers.

Comment: haven't used LEAD or LAG functions.using sql 2000 server

Comment: LEAD and LAG are new to SQL 2012 and not available in 2000

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the two tables together based on some common value. If the PRCSINSTANCE is identifying a job then the query would be something like:

```
SELECT m1.PRCSINSTANCE ,m1.PRCSNAME , --other static columns here
100 * (m2.jobtime - m1.jobtime) / m1.jobtime AS JobtimePercentChange
-- other calculations here 
FROM #JobTimings_JAN AS m1
JOIN #JobTimings_Feb AS m2
ON m1.PRCSINSTANCE = m2.PRCSINSTANCE;
```

For more information about how to use joins in SQL Server check out my join-series here: http://sqlity.net/en/1146/a-join-a-day-introduction/

Comment: Don't really agree with `m1.jobtime - m2.jobtime`. I think it should be the other way round, for, if the `m2` value was greater than the `m1` one, it would seem more natural for the percent value to be positive rather than negative.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Will try this out after the Christmas holidays and update you how it goes.